# running a script with an input file in python

Tags: python, fortran

I have a Python script that has to execute a Fortran code for several cases. The code requires an input file that is entered as a string.

Psuedo code

`input_file='input_'+case+'.in'
os.system('./a.out input_file)'`

Here case is a variable as it is different for each test case.
This is not working as I need to convert the string (input_file) to a file name essentially.

Comment: Maybe you could remove the '=' sign? Or is this a typo?.... os.system(<system command>)

Comment: Could you show us some [real code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? and your pseudo-code should be `os.system('./a.out input_%s.in' % case)`.

Comment: Save the data to the file you name and then use `subprocess` module to run the Fortran program (I guess it's a binary)

Comment: @cnnrzn edited the os.system command

Comment: @TarandeepKalra is this a python convention I don't know about? Also if case is not a string type you could do:    input = 'input_' + str(case) + '.in'

Comment: @cnnrznn no, i had not defined 'case'  in the pseudo code but it is basically a string defined earlier. Yes you are right about the latter half of your comment but in this I defined it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you use the new string.format convention to pass variables:

```
input_file="input_{0}.in".format(case)

os.system=("./a.out {0}".format(input_file))
```